# Find the unique value from multiple rows in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
ClassID DiagType
123     Final Dx
123     Primary Dx
789     Primary Dx
654     NULL
654     Final Dx
258     NULL
```

My table looks like the one above, if there are two of the same ClassID, I want to choose only one entry.  Long story short, I only want one entry per ClassID.

Comment: Please specify the basis for selection of DiagType in case of multiple options

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ClassID, min(DiagType)
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY ClassID
```

Comment: Hi Mikpa, that worked.  It worked well because F is before P and N is before P, but what if I had a DiagType of Doc Dx and wanted Final Dx.  The MIN would not work because it would pick the Doc Dx instead of the Final Dx.  How would you handle that?

Comment: well I know nothing of what possible values you want, but try MAX()-instead

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not specified which DiagType to choose in case of multiple options, I am assuming any one would do. If that is the case, the following solution would suffice. I have created a CTE so that can use identifier columns, if you have any

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY ClassId ORDER BY DiagType) AS RowNum,
       ClassId,
       DiagType
FROM TABLE
)
SELECT ClassId, DiagType
FROM CTE
WHERE RowNum = 1
```

Comment: Hi Shubham, Your solution  worked. It worked well because F is before P and N is before P, but what if I had a DiagType of Doc Dx and wanted Final Dx. The MIN would not work because it would pick the Doc Dx instead of the Final Dx. How would you handle that?

Comment: As I asked in the comment to the question, is there any fixed basis for the selection of DiagType?